# Do you know if have some limit of field quantity in visualforce for salesforce1?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, ios, jquerymobile

I have a big problem with my visual force for salesforce1. When I put more than 13 fields in visualforce, when I click in any field the visualforce scroll to top, to the first field that is empty. I tried a lot of things to work correctly, but until now I don't get.

The keyboard lose the field that I using.

I tested with 12 fields in visualforce and work perfectly, but with more than 13 not work.
This problem happen when I test in iphone, using one/one.app won't happen.

I'm using the frameworks below:

- jquery.mobili-1.4.3.min.css

  - jquery-1.9.1.min.js
  - jquery.mobili-1.4.3.min.js

Any people know what is happen?

Below a piece of my code:

```
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
        <div class="form">
                <form>
                    <label for="Name">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Nome" id="Nome" data-mini="true" value="{!Account.Name}"/>
                    <label for="DataNascimento">Data de Nascimento</label>
                    <input type="date" name="DataNascimento" id="DataNascimento" data-mini="true" value="{!Account.Data_de_Nascimento__c}"/> 
                    <label for="Email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" data-mini="true" value="{!Account.email__c}"/>
                    <label for="Sexo">Sexo</label>
                    <select name="Sexo" id="Sexo" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true" size="1">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="F" selected="{!IF(Account.Sexo__c == 'F','selected','')}">F</option>
                        <option value="M" selected="{!IF(Account.Sexo__c == 'M','selected','')}">M</option>
                    </select>


                    ........



                    <input type="text" name="NomeMae" id="NomeMae" data-mini="true" value="{!Account.Nome_da_M_e__c}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" value="{!Account.Id}"/>

                    <center><a href="javascript:SubmitData();" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="b">Salvar</a></center>
               </form>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
          <script> 
       //objeto
         var ClienteData;
         $j = jQuery.noConflict();
         Visualforce.remoting.timeout = 120000;

        //salvar os dados
        function SubmitData() {
            //loading
            $j.mobile.loading( 'show', { theme: "a", text: "Salvando...", textVisible: true });
            ClienteData.Nome = $j("#Nome").val();
            ClienteData.DataNascimento = $j('#DataNascimento').val();
            ClienteData.Email = $j("#Email").val();

            .........


            ClienteData.NomeMae = $j("#NomeMae").val();

            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.Cliente.submitData}',ClienteData,function(result,event){
            console.log(result);
                $j.mobile.loading( 'hide' );

                ...............


            });
        }

         $j(document).ready(function() {
            .......
        });
    </script>
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce inside Salesforce1 has a bug in this area.  There's a known issue that is not yet fixed at:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2oLAAS

I've also seen this behaviour with a regular HTML table and an onclick handler attached to the first column cell in each row, so I suspect you are seeing a manifestation of the same issue.

I was able to work around this by opening my page in a child browser (using window.open) after which it behaved correctly.  You lose navigation and the context that you are running in Salesforce1 however, so it may not be suitable for your use case.

Comment: Understood. I thought that was some thing in my code. This link I saw in my search, but how in this link mentioned just picklist/multselect I tried explore a little more. Thanks.